# Why I cannot import 'make_vec_env' from stable baselines？

Tags: python, multiprocessing, baseline

I have some problems with the example of stable-baselines and look forward to your help.

The environment is set as:

```
Windows 10
spyder 3.6
tensorflow 1.4.0
gym 0.15.4
stable_baselines 2.8.0
```

However, I cannot import:

```
from stable_baselines.common import make_vec_env
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-96-9dcb30379014>", line 1, in <module>
    from stable_baselines.common import make_vec_env

ImportError: cannot import name 'make_vec_env'
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the info. I've also updated the answer with instructions on how to update baselines.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the module we are talking about.

https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines

Seems like there was an issue that has been solved in 2.9.0:

https://github.com/araffin/rl-baselines-zoo/issues/51

Upgrade your `stable-baselines`:

```
pip install stable-baselines==2.9.0
```

And then it should be enough to use:

```
from stable_baselines.common.cmd_util import make_vec_env
```

Comment: I tried but get "Traceback (most recent call last):
ImportError: cannot import name 'FlattenDictWrapper' "

Comment: can you `pip freeze` in a shell and see which stable-baselines and gym you are using? If you add it to your question it will be easier to help. If you look in `cmd_util.py` you will see this import that it's failing. `from gym.wrappers import FlattenDictWrapper`